How can I increase the friction between the ferrules and the inline barrel adjuster?
The ferrule caps the cable housing before insertion into the inline barrel adjuster.

The inline barrel adjuster arrives already with a hint of light grease on its threads. For good measure, I add yet another touch of (heavy) grease, and carefully wipe the excess to avoid attracting dust.
Still, there is exceedingly little friction between the barrel adjuster and the (metallic) ferrule.
From experience, I know that I struggle with fine-tuning. When I turn the barrel adjuster, it is prone to spin freely on both ends, without changing length. This is particularly often the outcome when I'm trying to increase the length of the barrel adjuster. The design of this (all?) inline barrel adjusters precludes holding the inner part if it has disappeared inside.
This question is really a mechanical hacking question, but I figured given the context there will be someone here who has already come up with a good solution.
How can I increase the friction between the ferrules and the inline barrel adjuster?
A touch of super glue would likely solve the problem, but it's also unforgiving of a mis-application. I'm thinking of something a bit more subtle, such as thin double-sided supple fine-sanding paper, or the like. Have you solved this problem adequately?
Related

Does greasing the threads of an inline barrel adjuster cause slippage?
How can I lock a gear barrel adjuster that keeps moving?
Is there a convention for installing inline barrel adjusters?

Background Reading

What actually causes the barrel adjuster to change tension in a cable?


You want it spinning freely on the ferrule of the end indicated in the picture.
On the internal end (the other end, that part that moves inside the large outer bit with the finger knurling), choose a ferrule that will wedge itself in snugly. Common 4mm plastic shift ferrules or 5mm plated steel brake ferrules will typically do so readily. If you're working with fancy aluminum ferrules like the ones in the picture and they're running undersize and won't wedge in, and that's the only option you've got, this style of inline adjuster isn't going to work great. Even there you can still typically get it to turn by using both hands and slightly bending the housing going into that end to one side to get the friction needed. But, the intention with these adjusters is that with the ferrule wedged into the internal, moving end, in theory they can be operated by one hand.

Is another design, such as the SRAM inline barrel adjuster (https://www.giantancaster.ca/product/sram-inline-barrel-adjuster-179908-1.htm) better, in the sense that it can always be operated with one hand. I can indeed insert a pick hard enough in the inner (aluminum) part of the Jagwire barrel adjuster to stop it from spinning while I'm turning the outer part, but it's never fun to operate it that way.

My recommendation is any that have sprung detents (move in 1/4 turn increments), because the other kind can vibrate and change adjustment on their own.

You can use pliers to deform metal ferrules into a slightly oval shape which will make them sit more snugly on the housing and inside the barrel adjuster.
